# python3: bad interpreter: can't open a terminal

Tags: python

I did something wrong with python, I think I deleted some folders of it. Now I can't launch the terminal!

I opened `XTerm` and launched gnome-terminal and it is saying:

```
bash /usr/bin/gnome-terminal /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you reinstall python?

Comment: @HanAltae-Tran How can I procedure that?

Comment: Just link the `/usr/bin/python3` to the correct position where it is... Or download and extract one from the official site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up reinstalling the whole system.. Python is very deep and used in ubuntu systems so if you mess with it, the consequences are unpredictable. For me the best solution is to reinstall linux.

Answer (score 0):

Find all dependencies:

```
dpkg -l | grep python_ver
```

remove all the files:

```
apt-get --purge remove libpython3.5 libpython3.5-dev libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib python3.5 python3.5-dev python3.5-minimal
```

Reinstall:

```
apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

Comment: It is saying no package found  matching python_ver.

Package " " is not installed so not removed

Couldn't locate python3.5-dev

Comment: try writting \r\n after python3

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested by @Geno Chen in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106359/python3-bad-interpreter-cant-open-a-terminal/63509809#comment89215647_51106359), the simple answer is to link /usr/bin/python3 to your python3.5.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Things to note:

1. If this happened after trying to update python 3.5 to 3.6, then you need to verify that you still have python 3.5. If not then reinstall it.
2. Make sure you link python 3.5 and not 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 (after I fixed my Python3 version with `update-alternatives`).

```bash
sudo apt remove gnome-terminal
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```